# How to telnet using Telnet library of Robot Framework where there is no login Password required for Telnet to server

Tags: robotframework, telnetlib

How to telnet using Telnet library of Robot Framework where there is no login Password required for Telnet to server

My code is

```html
*** Settings ***
Library         Telnet


Test Teardown     Close All Connections


*** Test Cases ***
Telnet to DUT
    Open Connection  192.168.2.254  
    Login  ls  date  login_prompt=#  password_prompt=""
    Execute Command  ls
```

Just given ls and date to check since there is no username password required to connect. And by correct\expected prompt is #
And I am getting "ls" output as well but next time when it is expecting a Password prompt it is failing with the below error as there is no Password prompt
"*No match found for '""' in 3 seconds. Output:*"

Can someone pls help.. may be this is easy and I am not able to figure it out.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer, kindly ignore it.

Added   *prompt_is_regexp=yes  prompt=#* (This is expected prompt) in Open Connection and this worked.